# Octave shows gnuplot in interactive mode but not from command line

Tags: octave

I'm writing a script in the octave programming language that calls `plot`. When I open the octave console in interactive mode and paste the script in, gnuplot appears correctly. However, when I run the script from a command line via

```
octave ./myscript.m
```

all `printf` work, but no gnuplot window appears. This happens with as simple a script as

```
plot([0 1; 2 3])
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks.

Comment: What system are you using?  Windows or linux.  If I memeber correctly octav pipes your commands via a file stored in /tmp/ (on Linux). Looking at those might give you a clue as to what's going on.  Hmm, can't find a link for this though, will have a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running the script with the [`--persist` flag](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Command-Line-Options.html). This flag tells Octave to *"go to interactive mode after

`--eval` or reading from a file named on the command line."*

```
> octave --persist ./myscript.m
```

Comment: That did it, though it'd be nice if I could get Octave to die and only gnuplot to persist...